# Android app - can I see interesting questions?

Tags: feature-request, android-app, interesting-page

On the website the default list of questions displays interesting tab (which I believe has questions based on my highest scoring tabs). That's very convenient and allows me to check new questions that are relevant for me easily.

Can the same view be added to the mobile app?